# Starting new actionscript project in Flash Builder 4.7: no SDK selection available

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm using Flash Builder 4.7. When starting a new Actionscript Project, the first popup box where you define the project name etc doesn't show any SDK's. So under "This project will use" there is just an empty area...

And in the created project I also can't link to a Flex SDK in the Actionscript Build Path.

When starting a new Flex Project, everything is OK and I can choose between the different SDK's installed.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Frank

Comment: I don't see the issue. You don't need an SDK for a pure ActionScript project. (Except the compiler that is, but FB will use the compiler of the default SDK)

Comment: I had same problem awhile back with 4.7 - it started after i overlaid a different AIR SDK over Flex SDK (cant remember which versions). Seems that FB got a bit confused - something to do with the new compiler not liking the flex/air merge i had done. I had to reinstall FB

Comment: yep, tried that, even reinstalled the complete damned Flash Builder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem found and solved thanks to this blog post:
http://www.badu.ro/?p=238

Apparantly when moving from Flex Builder 4.6 to 4.7 you have to use new workspaces. If you reuse the existing ones from version 4.6 you run into problems like I was having...

Thanks for all your help,

Frank

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are seeing errors because your class has no package definition.

```
package com.something.something
{
// imports
import flash.display.Sprite
// class definition

    public class Something extends Sprite{

    }
}
```

But, you didn't show us the actual errors in your screenshot.  IF that is not the error, please provide the text of your compiler errors / warnings.  In Flash Builder, from the WIndow Menu select Show View and Problems.

Comment: This is the error message: Unknown Flex SDK: "Flex 4.6.0". Unknown Flex Problem

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd get that on an ActionScript only project in Flash Builder 4.7.  4.7 should use the new 'Falcon' ActionScript compiler  and not mxmlc from the Flex SDK.

Comment: I've heard that FB 4.7 is a total disaster. I switched to IntelliJ IDEA about 6 months ago (FB was at 4.6 at the time). Even though IDEA is not without its flaws, I wouldn't want to go back to FB even if they paid me for it.

Comment: I've heard similar things; although I've also heard it runs great on Windows.  In my limited usage; I haven't run into any problems w/ FB4.7, though.